# Proof of Hahn Banach theorem geometric form of Brezis : if $A$ and $B$ is disjoint, why introducing $C=A-B$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A\subset E$ and $B\subset E$ two convexe sets, non empty and disjoint. Suppose $A$ open. There is a closed hyperplan that separate $A$ and $B$.

In the book "Analyse fonctionnelle : théorie et application" (sorry it's in french), page 6 (demonstration théorème I.6) they do as follow : Set $C=A-B$. In particular $C$ is convexe (easy to prove), open (since $C=\bigcup_{x\in B} A-y$) and $0\notin C$ (because $A\cap B=\emptyset$.)

**Question :** What's the thing with this $C$ ? Since $A$ and $B$ is disjoint, $C=A-B=A$. So nothing to prove about the convexity of $C$ and the fact that $C$ is open... I don't understand what they try to do. Did they made a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing
$$A-B=\left\{x-y:x\in A,y\in B\right\} $$
with 
$$A\setminus B=\left\{x\in A : x\notin B\right\} $$
which is sometimes also denoted with $A-B$.

Comment: Waou... I would never think about $A-B=\{x-y\mid x\in A, y\in B\}$... Why didn't they precise it ? But anyway, thanks vvveerrrryyyyy much ! :)

Comment: @Peter I agree that the author should have specified the meaning, although this notation is rather common in this context.